# スパム等を理由に削除された投稿は内容自体が非表示になるよう配慮して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 仕様

スタックオーバーフローでは削除された投稿であっても、一定以上の信用度があれば内容を確認することが可能です。

この機能自体は意味のあるものだと思いますが、スパムや嫌がらせを理由に削除された不快なコンテンツも (警告無しに) 表示されてしまうのは問題だと思います。

現状でも文章はグレーアウトして表示されるので、目に入ってもじっくり読まなければある程度は無視できますが、画像に関しては大写しになることが多いので嬉しくないです。
(いくら信用度が高くても、不快なコンテンツに対しての耐性があるわけではありません)

直近で問題のあった投稿は気を利かせたユーザーが自主的に編集で元の内容が隠れるようにしてくれましたが、できれば (ボット = コミュニティユーザーによる) 自動での処理をしてくれると助かります。

案:

> この投稿は不快な内容を含むとスパム報告を受けたため自動で削除されました。
> 元の内容を確認するには [編集履歴] を参照してください。

Answer (score 1):

2023 年 1 月の [Catija さんの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385579/314875)には Imgur の自動削除があると記載されています。しかし、毎日行われるはずの自動削除が今回遅れてしまった理由としては、「CSAM の作業の一環として規制当局への報告に使用する画像を残す必要があるため、Imgur から自動的に削除されないよう削除設定が変更されていた」ということがあげられます。いずれにせよ、不快な画像を閲覧できてしまう状況の方は、おそれいりますがお問い合わせフォームから直ちにご連絡をいただけますでしょうか。

- お問い合わせフォーム　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact

「信用度がどれだけ高くても不快なコンテンツに対しての耐性があるわけではない」というのはおっしゃる通りで、もしも不快な画像が閲覧できてしまう状態の場合にはすぐに[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)で　@aki　までメンションをとばしてお知らせください。元の内容が編集履歴から隠れるようにできるだけ早く処理をいたします。